# Getting search bar ID for selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

Trying to get the search bar ID from this website: http://www.pexels.com

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\PythonScripts\\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.pexels.com"
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()


search_bar = browser.find_element_by_id("//input[@id='search__input']")
search_bar.send_keys("sky")
search_button.click()
```

However this isn't correct and I'm not sure how to get the search to work. First time using selenium so all help is appreciated!

Comment: You should read a tutorial on the different kind of selectors. The method `find_element_by_id` takes an id and not an XPath.

Comment: Reading a tutorial that uses that type of selector, may be why i'm lost, could you help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There's no id attribute in the tag you are searching for. You may use css selectors instead. Here's a sample snippet:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[placeholder='Search for free photos…']");
search_bar.send_keys("sky")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Above snippet will insert 'sky' in the search bar and hit enter button.

Answer (score 2):

[Locating Elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) gives an explanation on how to locate elements with Selenium.

The element you want to select, looks like this in the DOM:

```
<input required="required" autofocus="" class="search__input" type="search" placeholder="Search for free photos…" name="s">
```

Since there is no id specified you can't use `find_element_by_id`.

For me this worked:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header[2]/div/section/form/input')
search_bar.send_keys("sky")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

for the selection you can also use the class name:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search__input")
```

or the name tag:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('s')
```

However, locating elements by names is probably not a good idea if there are more elements with the same name ([link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-name))

BTW if you are unsure about the xpath, the google Chrome inspection tool lets you copy the xpath from the document: 
[image]