# python code to fill a search bar and get results

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am working on automating a manual task.
I extract a model number, example " ABCDXY" from an image. This model number has to go into "www.designlights.org" (That website has a list of energy efficient lights). (I have a code to extract the text from the image)
There is a search bar on the homepage of that website. If the model number I search is found, some details about the model will be displayed. If there is a matching result, then its an energy efficient light.

Ideal case:I need a screenshot of the result. But if there is a matching result, its okay to either display the result or send a message "OK" to the user.

To summarise: Search for that model number in the website, return the result. The search term would be dynamic and automatic.

Need a code snippet to make this work

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: I tried a search on google.com using,                                                                  "import  webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/#q=python')"                                                   and it worked

Comment: I used selenium driver and tried to connect the website. But, none of the options seems to work. This has a solution for a website, and it does not work for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497712/getting-search-bar-id-for-selenium . the website I am looking for is www.designlights.org. It has a search bar and I want to search in that.